# Slick carousel shows two rows instead of one

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I am building a website and I am using the [Slick](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) carousel for some sliders. I run into an issue where I have it set up with 3 slides and the option to show two rows if there are more than 3 slides, however, when there are 3 slides only it shows them in two rows for some reason. Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/petarvasilev/gt8Lrnzh/16/) demonstrating it.

Here is the JavaScript code:

```
var slickOptions = {
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3,
        rows: 2,
        dots: true,
        arrows: false,
        dotsClass: 'slick-dots slick-dots-black',
        adaptiveHeight: true,
    };
$('#slides').slick(slickOptions);
```

I tried googling the issue but can't find a solution.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this by getting the total number of slides and then conditionally defining the value of the `rows` setting. You should also set the value for `slidesPerRow`.

```
const numSlides = $('.piece').length;

const slickOptions = {
        
        rows: (numSlides > 3 ? 2 : 1),
        slidesPerRow: 3,
        slidesToShow: (numSlides > 3 ? 1 : 3),
        slidesToScroll: 1,

        dots: true,
        arrows: false,
        dotsClass: 'slick-dots slick-dots-black',
        adaptiveHeight: true
};

$('#slides').slick(slickOptions);
```

Comment: That solves it, but it introduces another problem. Now, slick-track is not taking up the full width of the parent element for some reason. Any idea why? Here is JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/petarvasilev/moq3ftu1/8/

Comment: I think you can fix that by altering `slidesToShow` depending on the number of slides and setting `slidesToScroll: 1`. I've added these changes to my answer above.

Comment: That didn't solve it, it's very weird behaviour... try it in the jsfiddle

Comment: This is working for me in your jsfiddle and that's more obvious if you insert some text content in each slide `<div>`. The remaining problem I've seen is that when you have a single row, Slick replaces your slide IDs (e.g. `id="slide-4"`) with its own, so you lose your individual background colors.

Comment: But why is it that, when you don't have slidesPerRow set the slider takes up the full width of the page and when it is set it takes up roughly 1/3 of the page's width?

Comment: If I simply drop my code above in place of yours in the jsfidde, I'm seeing a full-width slideshow for both 3 and 5 slides. Are you making other changes to the settings?